# How is class metadata related to spring annotations?

Tags: java, spring

I am very new to the subject Spring Framework. I am stuck as I couldn't get any clear picture of 
What is metadata?
How spring makes use of metadata?
And where is metadata generated?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Metadata is any sort of information *about* a class besides the actual code itself. The most common kinds of metadata are annotations, debug information, and external information such as XML descriptions or `spring.factories` listings.

Comment: For anyone getting error like `Couldn't read class metadata for interface io.fouad.ProjectionInterface. Input property calculation might fail`, the solution is to register the class file, something like: `hints.resources().registerPattern("%s.class".formatted(interfaceClass.getName().replace('.', '/')));`

Answer (score 2):

Metadata is what is also known as annotations in Spring when a class or method is declared and annotated it adds metadata (configuration data) to the class. Some Spring annotations are `@Autowired`, `@Component`, `@Controller`, etc.

The following example demonstrates how classes can be annotated in Spring:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class HomeController{
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String welcomeAll(){
    return "welcome";
  } 
}
```

Spring makes use of these annotations by scanning the classes registering them and injecting the necessary dependencies on to the object at compile or runtime for special processing that way the object comes fully bundled and ready for use. So Spring acts like a factory for object creation and it delivers to you composed object with all its dependencies injected.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Merriam Webster dictionary, ["metadata"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/metadata) means "data that provides information about other data".

In Java, class metadata provides information about a given class, such as:

- What annotations does it have?
- What constructors does it have?
- What methods does it have?
- What fields does it have?
- What interfaces does it implement?
- Is it `public`, `private`, or default (package) scoped?
- Is it `abstract`? Is it `final`? Is it `static`?
- What package does it belong to?

The `java.lang.reflect` package has various classes and interfaces that you can use in combination with `java.lang.Class` to obtain information (i.e. metadata) about a given class.

For example, let's say that you have a variable of type Object that may reference an instance of a random class:

```
Object o = getRandomObject();
```

where `getRandomObject()` ramdomly returns an `ArrayList`, a `LinkedList`, a `HashMap`, a `LinkedHashMap`, or a `TreeSet`:

```
public static Object getRandomObject() {
        double val = Math.random();
    if (val < 0.2) {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    } else if (val < 0.4) {
        return new LinkedList<>();
    } else if (val < 0.6) {
        return new HashMap<>();
    } else if (val < 0.8) {
        return new LinkedHashMap<>();
    } else {
        return new TreeSet<>();
    }
}
```

You can use `o.getClass()` to obtain an instance of `java.lang.Class` and use that to get class metadata about `o`. For example:

```
Object o = getRandomObject();
Class<?> classMetadata = o.getClass();
System.out.println("Class name: " + classMetadata.getName());
```

which depending on the random value of `val` may print:

```
Class name: java.util.LinkedList
```

You can also obtain other metadata information about `o`. For example, you can fetch the list of its public methods:

```
for (Method method : classMetadata.getMethods()) {
    String methodName = method.getName();
    String params = Arrays.stream(method.getParameters())
                          .map(p -> p.getType().getName())
                          .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "(", ")"));

    System.out.println("Method name: " + methodName + params);
}
```

which for `java.util.LinkedList` will print:

```
Method name: push(java.lang.Object)
Method name: addLast(java.lang.Object)
Method name: pollFirst()
Method name: addFirst(java.lang.Object)
Method name: offerFirst(java.lang.Object)
Method name: offerLast(java.lang.Object)
Method name: removeFirst()
Method name: removeLast()
```

You can even invoke a given method using reflection:

```
Method sizeMethod = classMetadata.getMethod("size");
System.out.println("Invoking the size() method: " + sizeMethod.invoke(o));

Method addMethod = classMetadata.getMethod("add", Object.class);
System.out.println("Invoking the add(Object) method: " + sizeMethod.invoke(o));
addMethod.invoke(o, "Some Value");

System.out.println("Invoking the size() method: " + sizeMethod.invoke(o));
```

which will print:

```
Invoking the size() method: 0
Invoking the add(Object) method: 0
Invoking the size() method: 1
```

With annotations you can attach additional metadata to the classes that you write and retrieve those metadata at runtime.

Here is an example annotation and a class that itself, its fields, methods, and constructor are annotated with that annotation:

```
@Foo(value = "some metadata")
class Point {

    @Foo(value = "some other metadata")
    private int x;

    @Foo(value = "yet some other metadata")
    private int y;

    @Foo(value = "some other metadata for constructor")
    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Foo(value = "some other metadata for vectorSize")
    public double vectorSize() {
        return Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Foo {
    String value() default "";
}
```

Now using reflection, you can retrieve this metadata at runtime:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class MetadataExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point p = new Point(1, 2);
        Class<? extends Point> pointClass = p.getClass();

        // class annotations
        System.out.println("--- Class annotations: ");
        for (Annotation annotation : pointClass.getAnnotations()) {
            System.out.println("\tClass name: " + pointClass.getName());
            if (annotation instanceof Foo) {
                Foo foo = (Foo) annotation;
                System.out.println("\t\tAnnotation: " + Foo.class.getName() + ", " + "annotation value: " + foo.value());
            }
        }

        // field annotations
        System.out.println("\n--- Field annotations: ");
        for (Field field : pointClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
            System.out.println("\tField name: " + field.getName());
            for (Annotation annotation : field.getAnnotations()) {
                if (annotation instanceof Foo) {
                    Foo foo = (Foo) annotation;
                    System.out.println("\t\tAnnotation: " + Foo.class.getName() + ", annotation value: " + foo.value());
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }

        // method annotations
        System.out.println("--- Method annotations: ");
        for (Method method : pointClass.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            System.out.println("\tMethod name: " + method.getName());
            for (Annotation annotation : method.getAnnotations()) {
                if (annotation instanceof Foo) {
                    Foo foo = (Foo) annotation;
                    System.out.println("\t\tAnnotation: " + Foo.class.getName() + ", annotation value: " + foo.value());
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }

        // method annotations
        System.out.println("--- Constructor annotations: ");
        for (Constructor<?> cons : pointClass.getDeclaredConstructors()) {
            System.out.println("\tConstructor name: " + cons.getName());
            for (Annotation annotation : cons.getAnnotations()) {
                if (annotation instanceof Foo) {
                    Foo foo = (Foo) annotation;
                    System.out.println("\t\tAnnotation: " + Foo.class.getName() + ", annotation value: " + foo.value());
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which when executed, will print:

```
--- Class annotations: 
    Class name: Point
        Annotation: Foo, annotation value: some metadata

--- Field annotations: 
    Field name: x
        Annotation: Foo, annotation value: some other metadata

    Field name: y
        Annotation: Foo, annotation value: yet some other metadata

--- Method annotations: 
    Method name: vectorSize
        Annotation: Foo, annotation value: some other metadata for vectorSize

--- Constructor annotations: 
    Constructor name: Point
        Annotation: Foo, annotation value: some other metadata for constructor
```

With Spring, you annotate methods with Spring's annotations. For example, you can annotate a class with `@Component`. Then when Spring starts up, it scans the classpath to find all classes that are annotated with `@Component` and it turns them into Spring Beans. Similarly it will check for methods annotated with `@Bean`, `@Controller`, etc. and it inspects their metadata and depending on the metadata Spring will perform various initialization activities.